# bitbucket pipelines refering to other branches

Tags: git, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to work with pipelines on bitbucket. One of the steps I need, requires me to use git parse-rev to another branch. However, I keep getting this message:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/otherbranch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree
```

(I tried it with and without origin, and got the same result).
Using git branch showing only the branch the pipeline runs on
Is there a way for me to get the state of another branch last commit? While this is not critical, it may help with faster deployment

Comment: The pipelines dont fetch history from other branches. try to run `git fetch --all` to fetch them

Comment: I may use it, thogh it will be an extremly long process by itself. I'm not sure it's worth it

Comment: If you know the branch you can also specify it, example: `git fetch -q origin "+refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop"`